# how to plot histogram with the first column value as x and the second column as y value?

Tags: r, plot

I have the following structure in a file:

```
2014  50
2012  60
2016  80
```

I wish to plot a histogram using the first column as x values, and the second column as y values.

I tried:

```
data<-read.table(fileinput.txt, header = T)
hist(data[,2])
```

but it only gives me two bars.

If I want to write this into an R script, how to save the image to a location on the server?

Answer (score 1):

```
barplot(dt$obs,dt$year)
```

Have a look at the other arguments as well.

You can use `jpeg` to save it to a file.